# React Native - How to localize app name?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, internationalization

I am using React Native 0.45.1.

For localization, I am using the 'react-native-i18n' package (version 2.0.2).

I want to know how I can localize my displayed app name in iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

This article contains a thorough explanation of how this works for ios:
https://hackernoon.com/localize-an-application-name-in-react-native-c36c4b2be7c3

As for Android, it's just about creating a file under 
`android/app/src/main/res/`
copy the file under values/strings.xml
put it under ur language-region specification
ex. `values-en-rUS/strings.xml`
and then change the app name in there